# Multipeer Connectivity: getting an invitation accepted (using built-in browser VC)

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to [follow the WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=708) to learn about the MultipeerConnectivity framework. After many false starts, the browser(s) show the peers, and invitations get issued.

But when I press "Accept" on the peer device, the browser keeps showing "Connecting" without end. I thought that the `MCBrowserViewController` took care of the logic and I could relax until the browser's user pressed Cancel or Done, and the delegate method fired. I bet it's something obvious, but it's eluding me.

Here's what I hope is the relevant code. I have it in the AppDelegate. NSLog statements in the various delegate methods get called as I would expect—except for the one in `browserViewControllerDidFinish:` of course.

Bear in mind that the browser and invitations do appear, so *something* is right!

In the @interface...

```
@property   (strong, nonatomic) MCSession   *theSession;
@property   (strong, nonatomic) MCAdvertiserAssistant       *assistant;
@property   (strong, nonatomic) MCBrowserViewController     *browserVC;
```

In the @implementation

```
static    NSString* const    kServiceType = @"eeps-multi";

// called from viewDidAppear in the main ViewController

-(void)     startSession
{
    if (!self.theSession) {
        UIDevice *thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    
        MCPeerID *aPeerID = [[ MCPeerID alloc ] initWithDisplayName: thisDevice.name];
        self.theSession = [[ MCSession alloc ] initWithPeer: aPeerID ];
        self.theSession.delegate = self;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Session init skipped -- already exists");
    }
}

// called from viewDidAppear in the main ViewController

- (void)    startAdvertising
    {
    if (!self.assistant) {
        self.assistant = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:kServiceType
                                                              discoveryInfo:nil
                                                                    session:self.theSession ];
        self.assistant.delegate = self;
        [ self.assistant start ];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Advertiser init skipped -- already exists");
    }
}

// called from the main ViewController in response to a button press

- (void)    startBrowsing
{
    if (!self.browserVC){
        self.browserVC = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:kServiceType 
                                                                      session:self.theSession];
        self.browserVC.delegate = self;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Browser VC init skipped -- already exists");
    }

    [ self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.browserVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you implement the `MCSessionDelegate` method `session:didReceiveCertificate:fromPeer:certificateHandler` method, it will intercept the peer's attempt to connect to the session. You should either explicitly approve that connection in that method or comment it out.

Details and lessons learned:

In addition to the code I showed, I had made stubby implementations of the various delegate methods. One `MCSessionDelegate` method is this one:

```
- (void)          session:(MCSession *)session 
    didReceiveCertificate:(NSArray *)certificate 
                 fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID 
       certificateHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))certificateHandler
{

}
```

Extending @Big-O Claire's above, I started watching all these delegate methods, Just In Case. And this one fired when the peer tapped the Accept button in the AdvertiserAssistant UI.

This method gives you a chance to decide if the peer is legit and not connect (using the `certificateHandler:`) if you don't want to. Apple says,

> Your app should inspect the nearby peer’s certificate, and then should decide whether to trust that certificate. Upon making that determination, your app should call the provided certificateHandler block, passing either YES (to trust the nearby peer) or NO (to reject it).

In addition, you get this tip:

> **Important**: The multipeer connectivity framework makes no attempt to validate the peer-provided identity or certificates in any way. If your delegate does not implement this method, all certificates are accepted automatically.

When I commented this method out, the connections went through — and THIS problem, at least, was solved.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and it turned out i was using the same session for both the browser and the advertiser.  split up the sessions but make sure serviceType is the same and it'll work like a charm

```
- (void) setUpMultipeer{
    //  Setup Peer ID
    self.myPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[UIDevice currentDevice].name];

    //  Setup Sessions
    self.advertiseSession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID];
    self.advertiseSession.delegate = self;

    self.browserSession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID];
    self.browserSession.delegate = self;


    //  Setup BrowserVC
    self.browserVC = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"SERVICE_TYPE" session:self.browserSession];
    self.browserVC.delegate = self;

    //  Setup Advertiser
    self.advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"SERVICE_TYPE" discoveryInfo:nil session:self.advertiseSession];
    [self.advertiser start];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! tried it and it didn't work, but helped me find the actual problem (below). Once discovery was working, I went back and tried with a single session, and it is working fine so far. Of course, I'm still just getting discovery to work, so I may need your suggestion soon. I'll file a report as things progress. :)

Comment: this one worked for me, was using the tutorial at [appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/) and it was using the same session for advertising and communication, the "done" button never fired.

Answer (score 1):

I've not gone the `MCBrowserViewController` route myself when working with the new MC framework, but from slide 51 of the WWDC presentation, it does look like the `browserViewControllerDidFinish:` is only called when the user presses done. So this callback is probably not where the problem lies if your peer is still showing up as "Connecting...".

I'm wondering if you have to connect your peers to a session manually. You're already setting the `MCSession` delegate, so I'm assuming you're implementing `session:peer:didChangeState`. Set a breakpoint and watch for when `MCSessionState` is `MCSessionStateConnected`. The only thing I'm unsure of is if you need to manually handle this on the advertiser side, the browser side, or both. If you could figure out at which step the framework stops handling it, that would be helpful.

Comment: Good idea, so an update: when I watch more delegate calls more carefully (and implement @Alla 's suggestion below) I see that I get `didChangeState` to **not connected** when the device rejects the connection, but no change when it accepts it.

So I'm still puzzled (and still looking). Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: I’m at this point also and my approach is to set a static optional called currentSession. In game I reference this object to send data packets. This way when the session reports not connected I can set this to nil and the game can handle network connection failures gracefully. That way I never refer to the browser session or advertising session directly.